# How to print only references?

Tags: bibtex

I tried this code:

```
\documentclass[11]{article}
\bibliographystyle{article}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{lit.bib}
\end{document}
```

The result is the file not found.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you be more specific, which file is not found?

Comment: I compile with PDFLaTeX with MikTex. There is no error and when I click to Display file, there is File not found.

Comment: What do you have in references.bib?? You might have to check this file for errors?

Comment: You also need to run BibTeX in between runs of pdflatex. Your editor probably has a button/menu item to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right (just tested, but replaced the `caops306` class with different variants, as it is probably a custom class), however you need to run the BibTeX program after a first typeset with pdfLaTeX, and another run with pdfLaTeX after that.

One thing you could do, depending on your editor, is scripting an automatic run `pdfLaTeX -> BibTeX -> pdfLaTeX`.

E.g. with `arara`, you could write this before your preamble:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
```

You could also use a `latexmk` script which will typeset as above.

Comment: Thank you very much